# Artifactory - Can a Admin user be validated through LDAP group?

Tags: artifactory

Can the Admin users in Artifactory be validated with the LDAP group. In short, we do not want to enable the user as a Admin in artifactory manually. We want artifactory to look at the ldap group and validate if the user can be a admin.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>No, you can't, and for a very good reason. Think about a change in your LDAP query schema. Everybody will be locked out forever.</strike>

[Since version 5.3](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.3) Artifactory supports granting Admin privileges to a group of users. 
This allows you to import a group from your LDAP or Crowd server and grant Admin privileges to the whole group in a single action.

Comment: This displeases me. You still have the admin user to fall back on if AD was messed up. You want people acting as themselves, not as admin, so an AD account is preferred. Admin could be kept in the vault if (when) somebody messes up the ldap config. Thank you for your answer though. It was helpful.

Comment: And just on time for you @DaveBrunkow – now it's possible :)